# How to target value in this type of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array stored in variable `$user_top_cat`. I loop through all the users on my site and this variable stores their top categories.

On a random user, `print_r()` gives us:

```
    Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [category] => 16 [count] => 8 )
[1] => stdClass Object ( [category] => 17 [count] => 2 )
[2] => stdClass Object ( [category] => 24 [count] => 2 )
)
```

Now, I want to store the category `17`'s count value in variable `$category_17_count` as a string. How do I do this?

Note that the `$user_top_cat` differs depending on which user I target...

Comment: Why do you need dinamic variables?

Comment: Dynamic vars might help you `${"category_".$my_way_to_access_cat."_count"} = $my_way_to_access_count`. Be the real question is why you need it. It is usually not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you'd want to but yes you could use the `category` to concatenate it and turn it into a variable then assign the value:

```
foreach($user_top_cat as $values) {
    $cat_num = $values->category;
    ${"category_".$cat_num."_count"} = $values->count;
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZAwLce)

Comment: Hey, what's that method called? I have always wanted something like that.

Comment: @philtune its called variable variables.

Comment: Cool, looked it up. I don't see, though, what the brackets (`{}`) you use are for?

Comment: @philtune so that you can properly declare the variable name. either you use `$variable_name = "category_".$cat_num."_count";` then `$$variable_name = $values->count;` or the answer above. same declaration. you can also use `{}` for hypenated properties like `$values->{'hypenated-property'}`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @philtune sure no prob, glad this shed some light

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
foreach( $user_top_cat as $myObj ) {
    if( $myObj['category'] == 17 ) {
        $category_17_count = (string)$myObj['count'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Will you could use variable varaibles, but how would you know which variables exist?

```
foreach ($user_top_cat as $cat){
      ${'category_'.$cat->category.'_count'} = $cat->count;
}
```

You'd probably be better using an array

```
foreach ($user_top_cat as $cat){
       $categories[$cat->catergory]=$cat->count;
}
```